# How to solve a matrix optimization using MATLAB cvx

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

[image: Problem.jpg]

I have an optimization problem shown in uploaded figure file.

Determining the optimal matrix X maximizing given objective function is the problem.

However, since the function inside the log-function is non-concave, MATLAB CVX doesn't work.

How can I solve the problem? How should I transform the form?

Please give me a hand

Comment: Have you tried ``fmincon()`` with nonlinear boundary conditions?

Comment: Oh I didn't know about fmincon(). I'll try it. Thank you for comment.

Comment: "fmincon()" doesn't work in complex numbers. Also the way to satisfy the constraint about Tr[XX^H] is unclear. How can I treat these problems?